# Spring Boot migration from 1.5.22 to 2.0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, migration

I migrate my app from Spring Boot 1.5.22 to 2.7.0 and I have a problem. Java 8. To migrate to 2.0.0 I have to replace save () with saveAll (), replace the postgres driver: compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.1-901-1.jdbc4' with implementation ' org.postgresql: postgresql: 42.2.9 ', I also add this line to application.properties:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = true. After that, I build without mistakes, but precisely: when I start shooting with Postman, with the correct token I get 401. (Before it was 200). When I started analyzing it, it turned out that after Spring migration, when the project is being built, postgres tables on localhost are created correctly, but they are empty, (that's why I get 401). I don't know how to work around it. Would you have an idea? I'm pasting build.gradle:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok" version "1.11"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

project.version =  '1.1.5'

jar {
    baseName = 'refurbishment'
    version =  project.version
}

sourceSets {
    util {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


repositories {

     maven { url "http://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo" }
     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version: '2.5.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-jwt', version:'1.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator:2.1.18.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version:'5.2.4.Final'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version:'16.0.1'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version:'2.8.2'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version:'2.6'
    compile group: 'net.sf.ehcache', name: 'ehcache-core', version:'2.6.9'

    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.9'
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version:'0.6.0'

    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version:'1.16.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version:'1.2'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version:'2.6.2'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version:'2.4'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version:'20160212'

    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version:'2.5.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version:'2.5.0'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml', name: 'classmate', version:'1.3.1'

    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:5.4.0'
    runtime group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.3.4.jre8-preview'
    compile files('libs/PDFjet-5.1.jar')

    testCompile(group: 'junit', name: 'junit')
    //DBUnit
    testCompile 'org.dbunit:dbunit:2.5.3'
    testCompile 'com.github.springtestdbunit:spring-test-dbunit:1.3.0'

    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version:'1.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version:'1.7.0'
    testCompile(group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version:'1.10.19') {
        exclude(module: 'hamcrest-core')
    }
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version:'4.2.6.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version:'2.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path-assert', version:'0.9.1'
}

bootRun {
    def profiles = findProperty('profiles')
    if (profiles) {
        args = ["--spring.profiles.active=" + profiles]
    }
}

task copyWebConfig(type: Copy) {
    from('src/main/templates') {
        include 'web.config'
    }
    into "$buildDir/libs"
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION: project.version])
    inputs.property("VERSION", project.version)
}

assemble.dependsOn(copyWebConfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved :) Added spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always to application.properties (working for Spring Boot 2.0.0)